# Calling an Oracle Stored Procedure from PHP without Waiting for the Procedure to Finish

Tags: php, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

PHP 5.2.5 - Oracle 11

I have a PHP web page that kicks off an Oracle stored procedure. This procedure takes several minutes to run and I'd like to show the current status of the process by checking current values from the database and display them as the web page refreshes every few seconds. The stored procedure runs fine but oci_execute seems to have to wait on the result before the PHP script continues. Is there a way to kick off this stored procedure without oci_execute having to wait on the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script can spawn a job that runs the procedure in a separate session using either the `dbms_job` or `dbms_scheduler` package.

```
DECLARE
  l_jobno pls_integer;
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   'BEGIN <<your procedure call>> END;',
                   sysdate + interval '1' second );
  commit;
END;
```

That will return as soon as the job is submitted.  The procedure won't be able to see any uncommitted changes made in your session and your session won't be able to see any uncommitted changes made by the procedure.  That may require more work to ensure that the procedure's execution can be monitored while also using transactions correctly.

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll check this out but can you tell me this; I'm currently passing parameters to the sproc. Is there a mechanism to send parameters to the dbms_job?

Comment: @Jeff - With `dbms_job`, you'd need to put the parameters in the string you pass as the second argument, i.e. `'BEGIN procedure_name( ''' || some_string_parameter || ''' ); END;'`.  If you define a job using `dbms_scheduler`, you can define it with parameters and then set the parameters before executing the job.